# Make popup fade in after 5 seconds and fade out on close

Tags: modal-dialog, popup

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/hb4bb761/

The popup currently appears immediately. How can I make it appear after 5 seconds and how can I make it fade in when it appears?

Also is there a way to make it fade away when closing it?

Here is the js in question:

```
$(function(){
$('#screen, #modal').show();
});

$('#screen, #modal button').click(function(){
$('#screen, #modal').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery provides such features already, you can just use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`

I adjusted your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hb4bb761/7/) here

If you want to delay the execution you can use `delay()`.

```
$('selector').delay(5000).fadeIn(1000)
```